# How to solve arcsin(x1/x2 * sin(theta)

Tags: trigonometry

$$f = \arcsin\left(\frac {x_1}{x_2} * \sin(\theta)\right)$$

I think this is a simple question, but is there an easy way of solving this equation?  Is there a way to solve without having to sin both sides of the equation?  Is there some sort of trigonometric identity I can use for this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the unknown?

Comment: You have three symbolic quantities (with unstated meaning) on the right. Could you please clarify what you mean by "solve"?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I meant simplify.  So if I had $arcsin(sin(\theta))$ it would equal $\theta$, but how would I go about simplifying the expression above symbolically?

Comment: What variable do you need to get?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$y=\arcsin (x) $$ means $$\sin y=x$$ so ....

> $$ \sin f=\dfrac{x_1}{x_2} \sin \theta $$

and:

> $$ x_2 \sin f=x_1 \sin \theta $$